# Problem with firebase auth providers (HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

Hello i have problem to had 2 auth providers and requireDisplayName.
My code :

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
 signInOptions: [
   {
     provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
     requireDisplayName: false
   }
 ]
});
```

Thank to help me

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: false
    },
            firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
  ]
});
```

I'm so dumb xD